# Visual Studio 2008 "Document Outline" stopped working for the main form in my project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm a big fan of the rather obscure "Document Outline" window in VS 2008 (it's buried in the View -> Other Windows menu).

It's the only way I know to get a view of the containment heirarchy for a complicated WinForm that has a lot of nested controls.

Some months ago, this just stopped working for the most complicated form in my WinForms project.  Now it just displays "There are no items to show for the selected document", no matter what I select in the designer.

No clue as to what broke it - the form contains a mix of common MS controls and some third party controls (mainly DevExpress).  Several SplitContainers, but Document Outline originally had no problem with these.

Anybody else seen this, and any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: "for the most complicated form".  It would only be *really* mysterious if this happened for a less complicated form.  No idea what the limits are, try connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some poking around, I solved the problem myself.

I just started deleting controls from the form, to see what would happen.

Turns out the 3rd party grid I'm using caused the problem - when I reconfigured it, the problem went away.  (Looks like a bug in the control, which I've reported to the vendor).

Interesting...misbehaving controls can break the VS IDE, not just your apps.

Comment: Sure they can. The controls are running inside the IDE in a very similar way to how they run in your application. This is why you can switch tabs on a `TabControl`, for example.