# How do I resync the Visual Studio 2008 Windows Forms Designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a C# Windows Form project and the designer view suddenly displayed just a blank form when I opened the project. Not sure what caused this, but it seems to have happened since I added a 3rd party control to the Toolbox. The designer code is all still there and when I run the app all the controls are working fine. Anyone got any ideas how I could resync the form designer so it displays the controls properly. This is a relatively simple form which I could easily reproduce, but I'm feeling a tad twitchy about it happening with something more complicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Delete any try/catch statements in the form constructor.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but the form constructor just contains the standard InitializeArea()

Comment: Just created a blank form project and of the 3 lines generated in InitializeComponents() (sorry meant that instead of InitializeArea() above), this one was missing: this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

Comment: woops, hit enter too soon! Anyway, I added it and it made no difference, so I then copied the whole of InitializeComponents() + the control variables to the blank form project & hey presto the designer updated all the controls. So I've tried to do the reverse on my existing project, ie blank it out and then reinstate, but still get a blank form. Anyway, at least I can copy the code over to the blank project and carry on from there :)

Comment: @rob: If you can copy and paste what you find in the designer-generated code file into a new form and everything works as expected, then the problem lies elsewhere in your form. Probably the constructor. Can you post the code?

Comment: Thanks Cody but I've sorted it. As is often the case, it was a really stupid error, I'd done a global change in the code of "Component" to "Components" and it had picked up InitializeComponents without me noticing it. The designer didn't like it even though the code compiled and ran ok. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @rob: You should post this as an answer (something like "Check your constructor method carefully. I made the following mistake..."), and accept it. That way, others who have the same problem and arrive here looking for a solution can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment to the question, but in a nutshell, the InitializeComponent() method in *.Designer.cs mustn't be renamed otherwise the designer can't display your form.

Answer (score 0):

3rd party controls can definitely break the Designer.  See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326268/visual-studio-2008-document-outline-stopped-working-for-the-main-form-in-my-pro) concerning problems I had with Document Outline, that were caused by an errant 3rd party control.

I'd suggest you search your project for references to the potentially offending control.  If you tried to add the control at some point, and the add failed, it might have left some remnants that are now screwing up the designer.  Make sure you are searching the .designer file as well - that's where controls usually get instantiated.

If that doesn't work, I'd try to uninstall the control from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The class Form expose a property called DesignMode which tells you if you are inside VS or you are running the app.
Usually I do this in my forms to avoid VS crap:

```
public MyForm()
{
   InitializeComponents();
   if (this.DesignMode)
   {
      return;
   }
}
```

Of course in order to see the difference you need then to rebuild the project and close all VS windows

Comment: What exactly does this accomplish?

Comment: With this one you do not execute any additional code if you are in the design time (VIsual Studio). So you should create your 3rd party control after that if

Comment: DesignMode has no effect in the constructor; code for which it would be useful should be in the Load or Shown events anyway